# Maven project compiles but there are missing imports in the workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies, m2e

I'm using eclipse Kepler with the m2e plugin and I want to modify a maven project and compile it. I first converted it to a maven project with `Configure -> Convert to maven project`, but there were still many missing imports. When I use `Run as... -> Maven install` the project compiles.

How can I fix the missing imports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tell m2e to update the project: Context menu of the project / Maven / Update Project...

m2e will then read the POM again and update the classpath and build the project again.

Make sure you have this in your `.classpath` file:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

Note: The actual syntax might be slightly different depending on the m2e version that you use.

Another common pitfall is the scope `provided`:

> `provided`
>   This is much like `compile`, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime. For example, when building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you would set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to scope provided because the web container provides those classes. This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is not transitive.

Note the last part: `not transitive`

This means you depend on POM A which says "I need X:Y:Z, scope provided". Your project will see this dependency but it won't be on your classpath at all.

To fix this, copy the dependency into your project with the same scope (`provided`).

Comment: Which scopes do you use in your POM?

Comment: Where can I see the scopes?

Comment: Run `mvn help:effective-pom` and search for `<scope>`. Don't forget quotes on the command line or the `<>` will cause problems.

Comment: Aaron Digulla: Each dependency has `<scope>compile</scope>`

Comment: Do you see the dependencies under "Maven Dependencies" in your project?

Comment: Yes, all of them except 2 have `[compile]` next to them, the other 2 have `[runtme]`

Comment: `[runtime]` means they are only available when you run the project, not at compile time. Are those the ones which cause the missing imports?

Comment: No, the ones that are causing the missing imports are not there at all

Comment: Which version of m2e?

Comment: 1.4.0. There are some of the missing dependencies in Dependency Hierarchy and they're marked as `[provied]`

Comment: Aaron Digulla: Sorry, but how do I copy it? It already is in pom.xml

Comment: It's in a different pom.xml. Tell m2e to open this POM file (-> context menu in the dependency view) for you and copy the dependency into your pom.